# Flutter gradle fail

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6 PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\android> cd app PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\android\app> flutter run Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering". Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode... FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\android\app\android\build.gradle' line: 24 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\android\app\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Lenovo.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\d81khdp8xardd7wyq2l66rfqw). > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60 * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 9s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done 11.0s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to upgrade your `MainActivity` file:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    // add onCreate method (if not exists)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // add this line to "onCreate" method
        this.getIntent().putExtra("enable-software-rendering", true)
        // don't forget to call "super"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

}
```

If this does not help try to change the `gradle` version to 6.5 in `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`.

If the problem is still there, then you can try cleaning the `gradle` cache:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

and project `gradle` directory

```
rm -rf $PROJECT/.gradle/caches/ && rm -rf $PROJECT/build/
```